# Using one csv file to determine which attributes in another csv file are present to graph with igraph in R

Tags: r, igraph

I'm currently working with igraph in R. I'm creating multiple plots for individuals in a network. To create each of these plots I need to read multiple csv files. The first csv file shows the interactions between the individuals and their twice weight associations, which looks something like below:

```
    Individual1,Individual2,Weight
    A,A,1
    A,B,.2
    A,C,.02
    B,C,.5
```

The second csv file I read in is for the ranks of those individuals. In the format below:

```
    Individual,Rank
    A,1
    B,5
    C,3
    D,4
    E,2
```

I would like to use the ranks to determine the size of the nodes within the plot and was using the code:

```
   plot(g, layout=layout.fruchterman.reingold,
       vertex.size=V(g)$Rank +20)
```

The problem I'm having is that there are always more individuals with ranks than the individuals observed for a given plot. Is there a way to create a statement which would ignore any individuals in the second csv file that are not present in the first csv file?

Comment: if `x` is your data from csv 1 and `y` is your data from csv 2. How bout something like `y[y$Individual %in% c(x$Individual1, x$Individual2),]`?

Comment: Should have said that I'm still very new to R. Would I put something like that in an if statement? So if those individuals are the same then it'll plot the graph?

Comment: `y[y$Individual %in% c(x$Individual1, x$Individual2),]` will return a `data.frame` with like `y` but only with the rows where `y$Individual` is in `x$Individual1` or `x$Individual2`. So you would probably want to save it as a new variable to be used in your code for plotting instead of the full `y` `data.frame`

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll try that and see how it goes.

Comment: I hate to be a pain, but I'm getting the error "no non-missing arguments to max;returning -Inf" Is that because some individuals have a rank of 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can remove them before creating the graph, or you can remove them when you are plotting them. E.g.

```
library(igraph)

D1 <- read.csv(textConnection("#
    Individual1,Individual2,Weight
    A,A,1
    A,B,.2
    A,C,.02
    B,C,.5"),
  header=TRUE, comment.char="#", strip.white=TRUE,
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

D2 <- read.csv(textConnection("#
    Individual,Rank
    A,1
    B,5
    C,3
    D,4
    E,2"),
  header=TRUE, comment.char="#", strip.white=TRUE,
  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

G <- graph.data.frame(D1, vertices=D2)

par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(G, vertex.size=V(G)$Rank*5+20, edge.arrow.size=.4)
```

[image: example figure]

Now if you want to remove the the ones that are not in D1, then do the following:

```
G2 <- delete.vertices(G, setdiff(D2[,1], c(D1[,1], D1[,2])))
plot(G2)
```